# tabular with different alignment for text and numbers

Tags: tikz-pgf, tabularx, dcolumn

i'm trying to make a table with bold text and aligned on the left in the first row. Whatever text must be aligned on the left and numbers on the decimal separator (","). I tried using `\dcolumn` but that didn't work. I also want some style features such as gradient black, vertically alignment in the row. In the bottom line the "total" is probably fine when aligned with the content of the 2nd column. Doing as in the picture, i.e. aligned with the 1st row, 3rd col. content and with the numbers just next aligned with the numbers of the above rows will involve multicolumns.

here is my mwe:

```
%% start of file `*.tex'.

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
%\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs,dcolumn}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\newcolumntype{,}{D{,}{,}{2}}

\begin{document}    
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lp{4cm}lp{10cm},p{4cm}}
  \textbf{date} & \textbf{opération} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{montant (€)}} \\
  \specialrule{2pt}{0pt}{0pt}
  janv. 2022 & transaction A & 100,00 \\
  fevr. 2022 & achat en ligne & 3000,20 \\
  mars 2022 & boutique bio & 228,21 \\
  \specialrule{2pt}{0pt}{0pt}
  & \textbf{total} & \textbf{3328,21}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

here is more or less how must look the output:
[image]

EDIT: actually the dates are given with the format dd/mm/yyyy in the .tex file. I use `isodate` with `french` option and `\printdate{}` to display any date. Is there a way to get all days vertically aligned, months too, and years too?

for example, with :

```
\printdate{01/01/2022} & transaction A & 100,00 \\
\printdate{01/02/2022} & achat en ligne & 3000,20 \\
\printdate{31/03/2022} & boutique bio & 228,21 \\
```

i'd like this as output:
[image]

Comment: Please post a *new query* for the issue of typesetting dates.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution that employs the `siunitx` package and its `S` column type. Note that I've kept some of the `\textbf` directives contained in your sample code even though they don't appear to be relevant for the screenshot you posted.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex   %% or pdflatex, etc.
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\newcolumntype{T}[1]{S[table-format=#1]}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref} % optional

\begin{document}
\sisetup{detect-weight,detect-family,
         output-decimal-marker={\text{,}}}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{} p{2.5cm} p{3.5cm} p{1.5cm} T{4.2} @{}}
  \textbf{date} & 
  \textbf{opération} & 
  \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{montant (€)}} \\
  \midrule[2pt]
  janv.\ 2022 & transaction A  &&  100,00 \\
  fevr.\ 2022 & achat en ligne && 3000,20 \\
  mars 2022   & boutique bio   &&  228,21 \\
  \midrule[2pt]
  & & \textbf{total} & 3328,21 \\
  \bottomrule[2pt]
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: can you use another package than siunitx. This one is known to crash the engine saying "Undefined control sequence". In my case the use of hyperref in my document is enough to make lualatex crash when adding siunitx.

Comment: @user1850133 - I can compile the code shown above *just fine* on a MikTeX 21.3 system that employs LuaHBTeX Version 1.13.0, LaTeX2e <2022-06-01>, and siunitx 2022-06-07 v3.1.3. Please provide more information about *your* computing setup. E.g.. which TeX distribution do you employ, and when was it last updated? Which version of the `siunitx` package is being loaded? Please also provide more information about the exact error message(s) you've encountered. E.g., *which* control sequence is undefined?

Comment: @user1850133 - You asked, "can you use another package than siunitx?" Actually, it would be rather difficult to replicate the formatting of the numbers in the right-hand column of the screenshot I posted with any other package than `siunitx`. For instance, the `dcolumn` package and its `D` column type will typeset numbers using math-mode Roman serif glyphs, rather than the text-mode sans-serif glyphs you say you want to employ. (The reason this issue doesn't show up in the screenshot you posted is that your code doesn't actually make the `,` column type do any work...)

Comment: @user1850133 - I went ahead and ran the code shown above on a **MacTeX2022 system** (LuaHBTeX Version 1.15.0, LaTeX2e <2022-06-01> patch level 5, siunitx 2022-08-08 v3.1.6, and hyperref 2022-06-20 v7.00s). Sure enough, the code runs just fine on that system as well. Hence, I'm pretty sure that your claim that "this one is known to crash the engine ... the use of hyperref in my document is enough to make lualatex crash when adding siunitx" is *not* valid in general. Do please provide some much-needed information about your TeX distribution, including when it was last updated.

Comment: i found the problem. Actually i was using 'pdftex' option in loading hyperref, i changed it with 'luatex' after reading suggestions and now using 'siunitx' is not causing any crash of lualatex.

Comment: @user1850133 - Glad you found the source of the problem. Aside: I would strongly question the need for specifying the `luatex` engine option when loading `hyperref`. The `hyperref` package usually does a very good job on its own of determining which TeX engine is in use. Specifying engine-specific options shouldn't be necessary *unless* you want to create a dvi file or an html file (say, via `tex4ht`) instead of the default pdf file. As you've learned the hard way, improperly managed engine-related `hyperref` options are definitely the cause of a great deal of trouble and wasted time.